# For every matrix $A\in M_{2}( \mathbb{C}) $ there's  $X\in M_{2}( \mathbb{C})$ such that $X^2=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, radicals

True\False?

For every matrix $A\in M_{2}( \mathbb{C}) $ there's  $X\in M_{2}( \mathbb{C})$ such that $X^2=A$.

I know that every complexed matrix has a Jordan form matrix $J$ such that $P^{-1}CP=J$, But it's not diagonalizable for sure.

Thanks

Comment: Assume A^2=0 but A is not 0. Then if A=X^2, X^4=0, hence...

Comment: Hence all the eigenvalues of $X=0$, and then $X^2=0$. Very nice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The $2$-by-$2$ matrices with no square roots are precisely those with Jordan form $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  <s>In general, every Jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ has to have size $1$ in order for a square root to exist.</s>  @Did indicates an elegant way to see this in a comment.

The [Wikipedia article on matrix functions indicates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function#Jordan_decomposition) how functions can be applied to Jordan blocks provided sufficiently high order derivatives are defined at the eigenvalues, and this includes square root functions.  For further details, a wonderful reference is Higham's *[Functions of matrices: theory and computation](http://books.google.com/books?id=S6gpNn1JmbgC).*  In particular, a sufficient condition for the existence of square roots is that every Jordan block corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ has size $1$.

Thanks to Marc for pointing out errors in the old version.  See [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/348218/).

Comment: why do you consider only 0 to be an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Nir: I'm leaving some details for you to work out, but what I'm saying is that $0$ is the only eigenvalue that can possibly cause a problem.  You can always find square roots of Jordan blocks with nonzero eigenvalues, and I recommend that you check this.  The Wikipedia article should help suggest the form if you get stuck.

Comment: The second sentence "In general..." is false: $$\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right)^2=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right).$$ Damn, comments won't typeset matrices correctly.

Comment: @Marc: Thank you.  $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 14):

As I was recommended , I figured out the answer, with the help of @Did and @JonasMeyer and here is my full explanation.

If A is diagonalizable, there's nothing to prove, cause we are under $\mathbb C$, so $X$ will be simply the roots of A's eigenvalues in the diagonal.

Let's assume that A is not diagonalizable, we know that every matrix under $\mathbb C$ has a Jordan form, so one of the jordan form that comes to the head is this nilpotent matrix : $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 0&0 
\end{pmatrix}$ . Let's assume that there's $X$ so that $X^2=A$, and $A^2=0$, so $X^4=0$, so $X$ is nilpotent as well, but it can't be $0$ , so it has to implies $X^2=0$, But $X^2=0\neq A$, Contradiction.

So We find one matrix that does not have such $X$.

Comment: This is excellent practice (for you and for the site) to show the proof you arrived at after the inputs from others on this page. Your proof is mostly correct, I will add two remarks. First, one cannot write that A=J with J=[0,1|0,0], but only A=P^{-1}JP for a given invertible P (and the remaining steps of the proof are easily adapted). Second, when you write that X nilpotent implies X^2=0, you might add the reason why.

Comment: I'll add a line to clarify the second remark of @Did 

Since $X$ is $2 \times 2$, its characteristic polynomial is of degree two, and characteristic polynomial of a matrix annihilates the matrix, Since $X$ is also nilpotent, $f(x)=x^2$ is the characteristic polynomial.Hence $X^2=0$

Answer (score 3):

This answer is just to indicate that in Jonas Meyer's answer the second sentence "In general..." is not correct: $$\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right)^2=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right).$$
I mentioned this as comment, but the matrices won't typeset correctly in a comment.

Now that I'm writing an answer anyway, I'll add that for any other $2\times2$ non-diagonalisable matrix, which one can write as $\lambda(I_2+N)$ with $\lambda\neq0$ and $N^2=0$, one can explicitly get a square root $\sqrt\lambda(I_2+\frac12N)$, where $\sqrt\lambda$ is one of the two complex square roots of$~\lambda$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/328663/18880) for the general case of square roots of complex square $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: The reason why the matrices were not shown correctly in your comment might be the problem explained in this post on meta: [Too long LaTex formulae not shown in comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5137/too-long-latex-formulae-not-shown-in-comments)