# All eigenvalues of matrix $A$ are real, then there exists $B$ such that $B^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Square root of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65227/square-root-of-a-matrix)

Prove that if all eigenvalues of a matrix $A \in \mathcal{M} (n,n; \mathbb{R} )$ are real, then there exists $B \in \mathcal{M} (n,n; \mathbb{R} ) $ such that $B^2=A$.

Could you help me solve it?

Comment: For example, the $1\times1$ matrix $A=-1$.

Comment: I think you mean that the eigenvalues are all non-negative. If $A$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite, then this is a well-known exercise. Maybe that's what you meant?