# A question about $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For every matrix $A\in M_{2}( \mathbb{C}) $ there's  $X\in M_{2}( \mathbb{C})$ such that $X^2=A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57292/for-every-matrix-a-in-m-2-mathbbc-theres-x-in-m-2-mathbbc-su)
>   [Square root of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65227/square-root-of-a-matrix)

Let $A$ be $n\times n$ matrix on $\mathbb C $. Can I find $B$ such that $B^2=A$?
If I can , how do I construct $B$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65227/square-root-of-a-matrix

Comment: or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57292/for-every-matrix-a-in-m-2-mathbbc-theres-x-in-m-2-mathbbc-su