# How do you define the square root of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

More specifically, how do you define the square root of an $n\times n$ matrix A and express it in linear algebra terms? Does this have something to do with positive semi-definite matrices and diagonalization?

Comment: I think this wiki article should do the deal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix

Comment: Related posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57292/for-every-matrix-a-in-m-2-mathbbc-theres-x-in-m-2-mathbbc-s, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65227/square-root-of-a-matrix, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72551/a-question-about-n-times-n-matrix

Answer (score 3):

Square root of a matrix $A$ is another matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A$. It might or might not exist and it might or might not be unique. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) for more.

Comment: "might or might not be unique": It is *never* unique unless $n=1$ and $A=0$, or unless you impose additional conditions such as positivity.  (If $A$ is positive semidefinite, then it has a unique positive semidefinite square root.)