# Square root of of real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> For any real matrix $A$, write down a sufficient condition for a real matrix $E$ to exist such that $E^2 = A$, and prove that this condition is sufficient.

How would I go about answering this question? I need a starting point please

Comment: What is E2? Is E the identity matrix?

Comment: You need to find sufficients conditions for a real matrix $E$ so that $E^2 = A$?

Comment: I’m not given anything for E either so I’m not really sure what’s going on

Comment: When you are given an exercise so badly thought take full advantage of whoever wrote it and answer it to your convenience. They only asked for sufficients conditions. So, you could give a condition as restrictive as you want. For example, $A=0$ is a sufficient condition. If satisfied, there is $E$, the matrix $E=0$, such that $E^2=A$.

Comment: Many answers have been given here already. Have a look, e.g., starting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93305/how-do-you-define-the-square-root-of-a-matrix).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Note that the OP wants a square root over $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you might start by investigating the case of diagonal matrices.  Then generalize a bit to diagonalizable ones.

On the other hand, examples such as $\pmatrix{-1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr}$ that have no real square root show you can't generalize too far.

Comment: So I would need a diagonal matrix that i can take the square route of?

Comment: That's a start, yes.

Comment: Thank you! Would that be my A or would I call that D. I know $C^-1AC$

Comment: If you call the diagonal matrix $D$, under what condition does $D$ have a (real) square root?  If $D$ has a square root and $D = C^{-1} A C$, does $A$ have a square root?

Comment: I honestly don’t know my heads fried

Comment: Hint: what does the square of a diagonal matrix look like?

Comment: So that’s a nxn  matrix  with a square numbers down the main diagonal?