# Prove Why $B^2 = A$ exists?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Define
>   $$A =
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 8 & −4 & 3/2 & 2 & −11/4 & −4 & −4 & 1 \\
> 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> −9 & 8 & 1/2 & −4 & 31/4 & 8 & 8 & −2 \\
> 4 & −6 & 2 & 5 & −7 & −6 & −6 & 0 \\
> −2 & 0 & −1 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> −1 & 0 & −1/2 & 0 & −3/4 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 3/4 & −1 & 1 & 0 \\
> 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
> \end{pmatrix} \in M_8(\mathbb R)$$
>
> Justify why there is a matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A$.

I think it has something to do with the Jordan normal form so I found it.

\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}

(I know the ones are under the diagonal, but I think it doesn't make a difference.)

I have no idea what should I do next, a help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How did you find the Jordan normal form?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You know, found the characteristic polynomial, found the geometric multiplicity and found the possible jordan blocks according to the length.

Comment: Seems to me like computing the characteristic polynomial requires either a computer algebra system or some judicious _ad hoc_ techniques; certainly evaluating a general $8\times8$ determinant of $XI_8-A$ seems humanly impossible!

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You are right, I found it via computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By putting $A$ into Jordan normal form you have found a non-singular matrix $P$ such that 
$$
A = P^{-1}CP
$$
where $C$ is your matrix shown above.  It is easy to find a matrix sqare root of $C$, for example, in the upper left start with $\pmatrix{\sqrt{2} &0\\\frac14\sqrt{2}& \sqrt{2}}$

Then $$(P^{-1}DP)^2 = P^{-1}D(PP^{-1})DP = P^{-1}D^2P=P^{-1}CP=A
$$

Comment: Thanks, I had written a matrix which was the inverse of the element rather than the square root.  I I am making  the correction.

Answer (score 18):

The theory reasons why are given above. To prove this however one simply needs to find a matrix such that $B^2=A$ in this case

$B=$
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 \frac{1}{90} \left(-\frac{75}{\sqrt{2}}-70 \sqrt{2}+181 \sqrt{5}\right) & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{180} \left(-\frac{75}{\sqrt{2}}-70 \sqrt{2}+91 \sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{120} \left(-\frac{75}{\sqrt{2}}-130 \sqrt{2}+73 \sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{4}{9} \left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}+10 \sqrt{2}-\frac{17 \sqrt{5}}{2}\right) & \frac{4}{45} \left(\frac{15}{\sqrt{2}}+20 \sqrt{2}-\frac{43 \sqrt{5}}{2}\right) & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{5}} \\
 \frac{15}{16 \sqrt{2}} & \sqrt{2} & \frac{15}{32 \sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{29}{64 \sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{90} \left(\frac{285}{\sqrt{2}}+320 \sqrt{2}-362 \sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{180} \left(\frac{285}{\sqrt{2}}+320 \sqrt{2}-182 \sqrt{5}\right) & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{120} \left(\frac{285}{\sqrt{2}}+260 \sqrt{2}-146 \sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{9} (-8) \left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}+10 \sqrt{2}-\frac{17 \sqrt{5}}{2}\right) & \frac{1}{45} (-8) \left(\frac{15}{\sqrt{2}}+20 \sqrt{2}-\frac{43 \sqrt{5}}{2}\right) & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\
 \frac{1}{12} \left(\frac{21}{2 \sqrt{2}}-8 \sqrt{2}+8 \sqrt{5}\right) & 2 \left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{24} \left(\frac{21}{2 \sqrt{2}}-8 \sqrt{2}+8 \sqrt{5}\right) & \sqrt{5} & \frac{1}{16} \left(\frac{5}{2 \sqrt{2}}+40 \sqrt{2}-40 \sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{3} (-2) \left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}+5 \sqrt{2}-5 \sqrt{5}\right) & \frac{1}{3} (-2) \left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}\right) & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{5}{4 \sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{3}{8 \sqrt{2}} & \frac{5}{2 \sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{3}{8 \sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} & \frac{3}{2 \sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-2 \sqrt{2}+2 \sqrt{5}\right) & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-2 \sqrt{2}+2 \sqrt{5}\right) & 0 & \frac{1}{8} \left(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}-2 \sqrt{2}+2 \sqrt{5}\right) & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{5} \\
\end{array}

Comment: This is hilarious

Comment: Thanks took work. (was bored wanted a technically correct different answer for no other reason then for the lols)

Comment: Amazing thank you very much!

Comment: Good candidate for the Guinness World Record of "the most complex exact matrix square root computation":)

Comment: You broke math.stackexchange.com!  I shudder to think what this looks like on a phone.

Comment: @shai horowitz If I understand well, there is a real complexity in this work.

Comment: I'm not downvoting because I don't think this answer is _bad_, but I'm boggled that this has twice the upvotes of the 'real' answers to the question.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Probably because it took a lot more work to come up with.

Comment: @IrregularUser Why do you think so? Alpha will cheerfully give me the square root of a 3x3 matrix in virtually no time and I would expect any CAS to be able to get an exact answer using the mentioned Jordan methods in less time than it takes to type up the input.  The hardest part of this answer by far would be the TeX conversion (and I would expect there could be some measure of automation in that too).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki "The hardest part of this answer by far would be the TeX conversion" this is what I was talking about. The time it took to type this up carefully would have been work in itself, and we shouldn't assume that the answerer just dumped it into alpha - they may very well have come up with the solution themselves. Regardless, the other answers are much easier to come up with (including thinking and typing) than this one. I understand why some may consider this to not be a "real" answer however - you don't really learn anything from this answer.

Comment: Would be good to have a proof of $B^2=A$. $\overset{\cdot\ \cdot}{\smile}$

Answer (score 7):

I borrow (and slightly modify) an explanation that can be found in the excellent thread 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14106/finding-the-square-root-of-a-non-diagonalizable-positive-matrix

$f$ being any function, sufficient derivable, one can write, for example for a $4 \times 4$ Jordan block:

$$f\left(  \left[
\begin{array}
[c]{cccc}%
\lambda & 1 &  & \\
& \lambda & 1 & \\
&  & \lambda & 1\\
&  &  & \lambda
\end{array}
\right]  \right)  =\left[
\begin{array}
[c]{cccc}%
f\left(  \lambda\right)   & f^{\prime}\left(  \lambda\right)   & \frac{1}
{2!}f^{\prime\prime}\left(  \lambda\right)   & \frac{1}{3!}f^{\prime
\prime\prime}\left(  \lambda\right)  \\
& f\left(  \lambda\right)   & f^{\prime}\left(  \lambda\right)   & \frac
{1}{2!}f^{\prime\prime}\left(  \lambda\right)  \\
&  & f\left(  \lambda\right)   & f^{\prime}\left(  \lambda\right)  \\
&  &  & f\left(  \lambda\right)
\end{array}
\right]$$

(it is based on a certain Taylor expansion of $I+N$ where $N$ is a nilpotent matrix).

It suffices now to take $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ to get for the square root of a Jordan block of similar form as above but $3 \times 3$:

$$\left[
\begin{array}
[c]{ccc}%
\sqrt{\lambda}   & \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}  & -\dfrac{1}{8 (\lambda)^{3/2}}  \\
& \sqrt{\lambda}   & \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}  \\
&  & \sqrt{\lambda}  
\end{array}
\right]$$

Answer (score 4):

The question does not specify the coefficient field. If it is the complex numbers, then it would have sufficed to check that the matrix is nonsingular, since [every nonsingular complex matrix has a square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/207029/18880). If the fields is the rational numbers, then no square root exists for this matrix. If it is the real numbers, then it suffices that all (complex) eigenvalues are real and positive.

In general for a nonsingular matrix over a field $K$ of characteristic$~0$, having a split characteristic polynomial all of whose roots are squares in$~K$ (so positive numbers in case $K=\Bbb R$) is a sufficient condition for having a matrix square root defined over$~K$. The proof of the latter is the same as for the complex case: split each restriction $R_\lambda$ to a generalised eigenspace for $\lambda\in K$ as $R_\lambda=\lambda I+N$ with $N$ nilpotent, then $R_\lambda$ has square root $\sqrt\lambda\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\binom{1/2}kN^k$ where $\sqrt\lambda$ is some square root of$~\lambda$ in$~K$, and $d$ is the degree of nilpotency of $N$. (Characteristic$~0$ is used for the binomial coefficients. Note that one does not need to find a Jordan normal form, just the generalised eigenspaces.)

For references to other matrix square root questions see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/348868/18880).

Added: In fact the condition of characteristic$~0$ can be weakened to characteristic not$~2$, since the binomial coefficients are well defined for that case after cancelling all odd factors from the denominator in the definition. Indeed, since only the existence of appropriate coefficients matters here, it suffices to remark that $1+X$ has an $n$-th root in the formal power series ring $K[[X]]$ whenever $n$ is invertible in$~K$ (here for $n=2$), which is easy to show through a process of Hensel lifting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the reference to your past treatment of the subject "this answer".

Comment: Thank you for reminding, I added the field.