# Existence of the square root of an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is an invertible matrix. Can we be sure that $A$ has a square root, i.e. like $T\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $T^2 = A$?

Comment: See [Under what conditions does a matrix $A$ have a square root?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65227/under-what-conditions-does-a-matrix-a-have-a-square-root) or [$A = B^2$ for which matrix $A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207029/a-b2-for-which-matrix-a)

Answer (score 1):

It is true and there are several prooves of this.

A possible proof is to use the fact that $\exp : M_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow G L_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is surjective (this result is not straightforward).

Then we can write $A = e^M = (e^{M/2}) (e^{M/2})$ and choose $T=e^{M/2}$.