# Jordan canonical form of 2X2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I got this problem:

Is it true or not that for every matrix $A\in M_2( \mathbb C)$ there is a matrix $X\in M_2( \mathbb C)$ such that $X^2=A$? prove the answer.

I know that we can pass to Jordan form, and I proved that this claim is true for all the Jordan forms except 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
any suggestions what to do with this matrix? and also, there is a general version of this problem? thanks for helpers!

Comment: Suppose there were an $X$ with $X^2 = A$. What follows about $X$ that contradicts the assumption?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57292/for-every-matrix-a-in-m-2-mathbbc-theres-x-in-m-2-mathbbc-s